# Virtual Environments in Python

Tags: python, installer, package-manager

Which are the virtual environments create tools available in Python (like `npm` and `yarn` in Node.JS) and how are packages installed and handled using those tools?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 there was [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) *(which you had to `pip install`*) but from V3.3 Python 3 comes with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in the standard libraries.

There are also numerous pip installable alternatives to the above notably [pipvenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

The built in venv (and the older virtualenv) work by you creating your virtual environment once to a specified directory such as:

```
python -mvenv ./myvenv
```

This creates a copy, (in the specified directory), of python, pip and the standard libraries, *(you can specify a specific version of python from those that you have installed)*. You can then, (at any time), activate it by running ./myvenv/bin/activate, *on windows it is `.\myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat`* which:

- Modifies your path to point to the copies of python & pip
- Modifies your pythonpath to point to those under ./myvenv

While it is active any use of python will use that environment and pip will install to it.  **(Note that associations are not modified so just running somefile.py will use the same python as it normally would).**

You can switch out of the venv with `deactivate`.

Note that [PEP 582](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0582/) proposes Python local packages directory which, if implemented, will reduce the need for venv/virtualenv, etc.

Comment: so for now, what do you recommend ??
Should I use venv ?? or are there other tools that can make life easy ?? like conda !

Comment: If you are using a standard python installation I would recommend starting with venv.  Anaconda is not a tool it is an installation package that includes the conda tool as an alternative to pip & venv or pipx.

Comment: thanks @SteveBarnes for the information.